# Using MDX, how can I return the .Name of a member which is the MAX for a specific measure?

Tags: mdx

This is my first time posting and I think it's a hard question.

Using MDX, I want to return the .Name of a specific member of a dimension based on the fact that in a measure I have found the MAX

So If I create a grid

```
Dimension X = Jobs
Dimension Y = Time
Dimension z = cause (not in grid)
Measure = Stress (1-10)

              July 1 | July 2 | July 3 | July 4
**Painter**        1 |      3 | **5**  |      2
```

You can see July 3rd has the MAX stress value now what I want to do is return the member name of dimension z without slicing on it (it is linked with the Jobs dimension so if I do slice on that it is valid).

So [Dimension z].[cause].CurrentMember.Name
would give me the All member name but I need the MAX of measure stress to relate to this and give me the member name of cause that relates to this value.

I hope this makes sense and might even be possible?

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
WITH Member Measures.[Name of Max Stress] AS
     TopCount([DimZ].[AttribZ].[AttribZ].Members, 1, Measures.[Stress]).Item(0).Item(0).Name
SELECT [DimZ].[HierZ].[Month].Members
       on columns,
       { Measures.Stress, Measures.[Name of Max Stress] }
       on rows
  FROM [cube]
```

should give what you want.

It first uses the [`TopCount` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx), which sorts the `[DimZ].[AttribZ].[AttribZ].Members` set descending by `Measures.[Stress]`. As `TopCount` returns a set, but we need a member next, we use the [`Item` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145501.aspx), where the first call returns the first (and only) tuple of the set, and [the second call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145562.aspx) returns the first (and only) member from the tuple. Then we have a member, and can finally apply the [`Name` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145583.aspx).